# Objects in Isometric

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, isometric

I am trying a tutorial from [glacialflame.com](http://glacialflame.com/) (Great tutorials how to create isometric graphics in HTML5 Canvas!)

Now I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/fUm6n/3/

In this example is an isometric map with objects. Tile widths are 50, heights are 25, and the objects are the same size as tiles (and objects can be draw in only one tile).  How would I create another type of object that has something like a width of 200, height of 100, and draws in 4 tiles?  Would I create another object `Array` and set the sizes for this array, or is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert. However i've promised myself to read "html5 canvas" book when I'll have more time.

I think that you've two ways:

1. You can use bigger tiles (but this is convenient if all you're game objects have the    same dimensions)
2. You can have have, as you proposed, the same tiles dimension (50 * 25), but using more tiles in order to draw a bigger object (i.e.: an object 200 * 100).
   I suggest this approach in case you've different objects of different dimensions.

The final choice it's up to you.